# Parsing http response to store in shared_preferences

Tags: json, dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have an API endpoint returning a JSON response that is of type String. I need to parse this string and turn each JSON object into something that I can store in a List.

I have tried mapping over the response, but since it is returned as one whole string, I cannot map over each JSON object. The String current being returned looks like this:

```
[{OrgName: TEST NON-SCHOOL ENTITY, OrgID: 1111, OrgState: KY, OrgCity: 
TEST}, {OrgName:  Test School, OrgID: 426, OrgState: KY, OrgCity: TEST}, 
{OrgName: NON-SCHOOL, OrgID: 1, OrgState: KY, OrgCity: null}]
```

The goal is to store this into shared_preferences so that I can access it in a different screen in my app. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences

I think the best way for me to store this is to parse this string in a way that I end up being able to use shared_preferences `setStringList()` but because it is returned as a string in the `response.body` I am unsure of how to parse through this.

Comment: shared pref is not a database. use sqlite

Comment: See these SO answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889973/flutter-saving-user-data/53890058#53890058), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968769/flutter-how-to-decode-this-complex-json-string/53971119#53971119), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962129/how-to-check-for-null-when-mapping-nested-json/53962541#53962541). Look if they could put you in the right direction.